# Spark saving parquet files process takes too long (indeed?)

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to figure out if the time it takes to my job to read and write files from and to S3 makes sense.
I run a job that reads data from Delta lake, in the size of 2TB (partitioned by dates and hours - about 90 days and 24 hours per day) and saves it to S3.

The code which saves it to S3 is -

```
rawData.write
       .partitionBy("id", "dt")
       .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
       .parquet(outputPath)
```

It takes 90 minutes for the process to finish when I use 350 AWS spots (type m5.2xlarge) on the Hadoop cluster.
I'm trying to find some benchmark to understand if it makes sense or if something goes wrong.

Can some help? If any other details can help, please let me know, and I'll add them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing any kind of spark executor tuning? If not, try it out. Here is a good example [executor tuning](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/). Also check the spark UI and see if the jobs are distributed properly across executors or if there is something thats getting stalled. Can help more if you could give more details.

Comment: I'll try to add more details. Can you tell if the time it takes sounds logical or suspicious? Only based on the number of spots and the size of the data.

Comment: Looks odd. 350 instances is too much. I have personally used a smaller cluster configuration (around 20, cant remember right now) to process ~10TB data.